# How can I correctly upload a file in php?

Tags: php

Below I have the following scripts. The first is my upload.html is my upload form. The second is upload.php. I have a directory called uploads in the same directory as my upload.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the second php script.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I get this error.

> > File is an image - image/jpeg.
> >     Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/CodingTutorialsBanner.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php on line 38
> >     Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php5lGytz' to 'uploads/CodingTutorialsBanner.jpg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php on line 38
> >     Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Comment: This is the directory read/write permission error. make sure your destination folder where you moving uploaded file has read/write permission.

Comment: add this 
 `chmod("path_to_your_upload_folder",0755);`